# Want to Run Unit Test cases on a remote Unix server from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, ant, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have an ANT build.xml, which runs our Junits and generates xml reports. The way our Jenkins CI is designed is as below:

There is a farm of build servers provided to me by a third party team which manages jenkins. Based upon the load and restrictions in the job configuration the code gets pulled there and built. Post this the artifact is send and deployed on my application server.

My junits refer to certain environment variables. These are only present on my application server and not on the Jenkins build servers. Hence, when I run the build.xml on the Jenkins build servers all the Junits fail there.

As per my understanding, when we run the build.xml on the Jenkins workspace, it will refer to the project structure there. Also, in addition to that after the junits are run, the xml reports need to be present in the Jenkins workspace itself so as to render a graph for the same.

Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Note: I do not have the flexibility to ask for a build slave on my app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables during a build using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) if you're using a Freestyle job, or with the [`environment`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) block in a Declarative Pipeline job, or using a [`withEnv`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables) block in a Scripted Pipeline job.

Comment: With the EnvInject Plugin, will it be able to inject the setups on my app server and build the application on the build server?

Comment: You'd need to be a lot clearer in your question about what the relationship between the two is. The EnvInject Plugin will let you inject environment variables which will be available on the Jenkins build agent, during the build. This is what you said was missing.

Comment: Ok... I do not have the privileges to install any setup on the Jenkins build server, since this is managed by third party. However, I have the setups done on my application server. Can I make the build server refer to the setups done on my application server?

Comment: If you can fetch a list of the environment variables from the app server somehow, you could write them to a properties file, and load them using an EnvInject build step. Then those environment variables would be available for subsequent build steps.